# How to make a discord bot generate invite links from other servers, (Discord.py or py-cord)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a **discord bot** in discord.py, py-cord, and I was wondering if it's possible to have the bot **generate a discord invite** for a server and **send it to you** and how to do it?

*Is it possible?
And if so how do I do it?*

I have figured it out thx for the help.

```py
@client.command()
async def getinv(ctx):
    invites = []
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for c in guild.text_channels:
            # make sure the bot can actually create an invite
            if c.permissions_for(guild.me).create_instant_invite:
                invite = await c.create_invite()
                invites.append(invite)
                await ctx.send(invite)
                break
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the docs? You can easily find what you're looking for [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

Comment: I've read the api and didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Not possible. Try searching up `create_invite` in there? There are multiple places where it can be used.

Comment: Hm, I'll look again

Comment: @12944qwerty fixed

Comment: Instead of editing the question with the answer, please make an answer.

Comment: Please be careful when using a command like this, as this is commonly known as a **backdoor** if you are joining a server you are not already in and is against discord's ToS.

Comment: As mentioned , @Scripter Better to create and accept an answer. you are free to accept your own answer, though you won't get any rep from it.

Comment: @Bagle I do not mean to break discord's ToS I am just using this to join a server and then make my bot leave it. Some server's I dont want my bot to be involved in.

Comment: There are better ways to do this, such as getting the server's id and using the [`guild.leave`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=leave#discord.Guild.leave). This is a better method than risking a ban.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly improved version of the previous guys code

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        discord_guild = client.get_guild(int(guild.id))
        link = await discord_guild.text_channels[0].create_invite()
        print(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted to do the same thing, and I put together this script that prints invites to every server the bot is in.

```py
from discord.utils import get
import discord
import asyncio


client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = "token here"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Bot is up and running.')
  print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message, *ctx):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        discord_guild = client.get_guild(int(guild.id))
        link = await discord_guild.text_channels[0].create_invite()
        print(link)
        asyncio.sleep(750)

client.run(TOKEN)
```